# C++ /CLI Automatic Wrapper Generator

Tags: .net, interop, c++-cli

In our project we have a significant amount of native C++ code which we'd like to re-use from a brand new UI layer that is to be written in .Net.

I'd like to use C++/CLI for this matter and I've seen that there is a pretty straight-forward and rather technical way to do it by wrapping native classes with thin managed classes.
I'd expect to be able to find a tool which automates this task since it seems to me really as a technical issue without a lot of required "human" thinking.

There is such tool which uses explicit p/invoke for this - see http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html. The thing is that explicit p/invoke is more cumbersome and less efficient in performance.

Is there anyone out there who is familiar with such tool?

Is there an inherent reason why such tool is not available yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason p/invoke is less efficient is because it has to be a very generic interface to any function, knowing only the signature.  Your hypothetical wrapper generator will perform no better.

On the other hand, the developer coding a custom wrapper class has a lot more information about functions that get used together and so on, and can therefore avoid a lot of slow and unnecessary conversions, for example by storing values directly inside the wrapper and not converting them to some .NET-friendly format.

So it's not that such a tool is impossible, there's just little-to-no benefit to it.  If you care about performance, you write your own wrapper, complete with lifetime-management smart pointers and the like.

Of course, p/invoke only provides access to bare functions.  That's where SWiG should be helpful, to expose any C++ class interfaces via bare exported functions.

I did find one lead on a tool that might be what you're looking for, although it sounds pretty narrow in focus:

- http://www.ogre3d.org/addonforums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=4071
- example output: http://extramegablob.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/MOIS/MOIS/include/auto/MOISEffect.h

Comment: Tell me about little-to-no benefit. I am writing a C++/CLI wrapper right now and have just spent the last hour mostly copy and pasting enum types and changing `LONGLONG` to `Int64` , `LPWSTR` into `String^`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Explicit p/invoke is not neccessary bad. It really depends. The following links contains additional information you may be interested in reading. As they have experienced in their specific examples, P/Invoke with suppressed security is faster than any other methods of calling into native DLLs, including C++/CLI.

http://rogue-modron.blogspot.com/2011/11/invoking-native.html

http://ybeernet.blogspot.com/2011/03/techniques-of-calling-unmanaged-code.html

We have a tool you may be interested in using. It is a C# wrapper generator for C++ DLL. Only the C++ DLLs compiled by VS are supported.

With the tool, you can generate C# wrapper library directly from the DLL file and the C++ header files. It generates a Visual Studio project with all the C# class files. All the standard c++ classes, template classes, your own classes are supported. You don't have to write a single line of code.

Please read the detail at the link below.

[C#/.NET PInvoke Interop SDK](http://www.xinterop.com/index.php/2013/04/13/introduction-to-c-pinvoke-interop-sdk)

(I am the author of the tool)

Comment: Tried to install... can't even test this without registration. And no info about license costs on the website. :-(

Comment: @Beachwalker We are very sorry that you are having issues with the installation. The installation actually only asks for any non-disposable email address so that an activation code can be sent to you. Any email from yahoo, hotmail, gmail should work. As for the license cost, we will be glad to send you all the pricing and licensing document if you contact us on our web site. We are in the middle of making xInterop a full bridge between C++ and .NET world, which means it can also create C++ wrapper for any .NET assembly besides creating C# wrappers for native C++ DLLs. Hope you understand.

Comment: @xinterop - what you have stated is just plainly not true. I have tried to install your tool and it **does not accept web based emails**, so no way to try it for indie projects.

Comment: @Flot2011, What I said was true at the time when I wrote it, It has been almost 3 years since I wrote it. We have now changed the policy to only accept non-free email accounts. gmail, yahoo, hotmail, such free email accounts are no longer accepted. I am so sorry for any inconvenience.